# Valid US visa on expired passport. Can I travel to the US?

Tags: visas, usa, passports, b1-b2-visas

My old passport is in my maiden name and has already expired. My B1/B2 visa to travel to United States is still valid but is stamped in my old passport with my maiden name.

My new passport has my new name (old name got changed after marriage) but has details (like old passport number, father and mother's name) related to my old passport.

Will I be allowed to travel to US as long as I carry the my old as well as new passport? 
Or Do I need to again get the visa stamped on my new passport?

Answer (score 11):

There is a Q&A about this on the [U.S. Visas](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html) site:

> **My old passport has already expired. My visa to travel to the United States is still valid but in my expired passport. Do I need to apply for a new visa with my new passport?**
>
> No. If your visa is still valid you can travel to the United States with your two passports, as long as the visa is valid, not damaged, and is the appropriate type of visa required for your principal purpose of travel. (Example: tourist visa, when your principal purpose of travel is tourism). Both passports (the valid and the expired one with the visa) should be from the same country and type (Example: both Uruguayan regular passports, both official passports, etc.). When you arrive at the U.S. port-of-entry (POE, generally an airport or land border) the Customs and Border Protection Immigration Officer will check your visa in the old passport and if s/he decides to admit you into the United States they will stamp your new passport with an admission stamp along with the annotation "VIOPP" (visa in other passport). Do not try to remove the visa from your old passport and stick it into the new valid passport. If you do so, your visa will no longer be valid.

Answer (score 0):

You are good to go as long as you carry both passports, since your name has changed I would also consider you to carry any other documentation that proves it. But anyway, your visa is still valid :)