# Can I use a US visa in a official but cancelled passport?

Tags: visas, passports, indian-citizens

I would like to know the following:

Assumption: suppose a person has surrendered/cancelled his Indian official passport and gotten back his regular passport, but he has a US visa valid until 2020 in his official passport.

Can he travel to the US with the new official passport and enter with the visa in the surrendered/cancelled passport?

Comment: Please don't write in all caps.  It's difficult to read.

Comment: From that proposed duplicate, the answer appears to be "you need a new visa", since the type of passport has changed.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert but the question asks "can he travel with new official passport?"

Comment: @phoog you are right but the question seems to contradict itself over the issue.

Answer (score 1):

A valid visa in an expired or cancelled passport may be used in conjunction with a valid passport [of the same type issued by the same country](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/39315/19400).  Of course, the visa must be valid for the purpose of travel as well.

You write that you have "surrendered" your passport.  If you did not get it back after it was cancelled, you are no longer in possession of your valid visa, and you will need to apply for a new visa.

Also, in one paragraph you write "and got back his regular passport" but in another you wrote "with new official passport," so I would like to underscore the requirement that the valid passport must be of the same type.  You cannot use a visa in a cancelled official passport along with a valid regular passport.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use your old passport's visa with your new passport!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you expand on this? We're looking for answers with more detail and, ideally, references to official sources. For example, a quotation from the US State Department website would be much more convincing than "It's OK. Trust me! I'm an anonymous guy on the internet."